# Conditional display based on product category in processing order email template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, orders

I am working on the code of **`customer-processing-order.php`** WooCommerce email Template.

I want to display the code below, only if an order item has a defined product category of ordered item.

```
<p><?php _e( "Your order has been received and is now being processed. Your order details are shown below for your reference:", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
```

Something like:

```
if($categ="demo1"){
<p><?php _e( "Your order has been received and is now being processed. Some text here:", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
}
```

Here is an extract of the template code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer processing order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<p><?php _e( "Your order has been received and is now being processed. Your order details are shown below for your reference:", 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

<?php

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_schema_markup() Adds Schema.org markup.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_meta() Shows order meta data.
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::customer_details() Shows customer details
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_address() Shows email address
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_customer_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_footer() Output the email footer
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_footer', $email );
```

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it's what you are expecting. I use the WordPress native conditional function **`has_term()`**. This function accept term IDs, term names or term slugs, in a string for a single term or in an array for multiple terms.

You will have to define your category or your categories (see the comment in both codes).

Here is the customized template code *(for one category)*:

```
<?php
/**
 * Customer processing order email
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     2.5.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

//Define below your category (ID, slug or name)
$category = 'my_category';

$has_category = false;
foreach( $order->get_items() as $order_item ) {
    if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $order_item["product_id"] ) ) {
        $has_category = true;
        break;
    }
}

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::email_header() Output the email header
 */

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_header', $email_heading, $email ); ?>

<?php
// Here is your conditional statement based on a defined product category
if( $has_category ){
    echo '<p>'. __( "Your order has been received and is now being processed. Some text here:", 'woocommerce' ) .'</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>'. __( "Your order has been received and is now being processed. Your order details are shown below for your reference:", 'woocommerce' ) .'</p>';
}
?>

<?php

/**
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_details() Shows the order details table.
 * @hooked WC_Emails::order_schema_markup() Adds Schema.org markup.
 * @since 2.5.0
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );

# ... etc ...
```

If you have multiple categories, the code will be very similar:

```
//Define below your categories in the array (IDs, slugs or names)
$categories = array('my_category1', 'my_category2', 'my_category3');

$has_category = false;
foreach( $order->get_items() as $order_item ) {

    if( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $order_item["product_id"] ) ) {
        $has_category = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

All code is tested and working.

---

Reference: [WordPress Function Reference — has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. However, it is not working in the email-footer.php template. ?? Do you know why ?

Comment: @eberswine Because the order object is not defined, so not accessible

Comment: Gotcha.. Any way to integrate that ?

Comment: @eberswine You should try to ask a question in Stack overflow…

Answer (score 0):

just need to add php snippet in function file or in code snippet also you need to write categor slug

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'ts_email_before_order_table', 10, 4 );

function ts_email_before_order_table( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
//Define below your category (ID, slug or name)
$category = 'christian-harp-music';

$has_category = false;
foreach( $order->get_items() as $order_item ) {
    if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $order_item["product_id"] ) ) {
        $has_category = true;
        break;
    }
}


if( $has_category ){
    echo '<p>'. __( "We pray our music will be a blessing to you and everyone that hears it!", 'woocommerce' ) .'</p>';
} else {
    echo '<p>'. __( " We pray our books will teach your children Christ-like character!", 'woocommerce' ) .'</p>';
}
}
```